# Running a .sh file but after new PATH is not visible in shell

Tags: terminal, macos, bash, command-line

I am running a file ./setWLSEnv.sh which has the following output:

http://pastebin.com/sSXRZd1s

```
    PATH=/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/bin:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.
ant_1.9.2/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/H
ome/jre/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:
/Users/cris/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbi
n:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlser
ver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.0.5/bin


Your environment has been set.
```

BUT when i go in the same terminal and i execute

echo PATH is still have the old path ...

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Do you have the contents of the script? That way we can see if its being properly executed?

Comment: yes http://pastebin.com/sSXRZd1s

Comment: Can we see the script here - or better just the bits needed to provide an example that fails - it should; not be via a link only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a script to set the path in your current shell. In your case this does not  seem to be necessary anyway because all the script does is to set up the correct variables to run the java process at the end. So inside this process all environment variables should be set correctly.

To set variables in the current shell, either set them in `.bashrc`/`.bash_profile` and open a new shell; or duplicate your script, remove the last line and source the new script into the shell with `. path/to/new/script`.

Comment: sorry...the last line was added by me cause it was the only way to make it work,the original file does not have the last line.

Comment: you were right !

Comment: . path/to/new/script works...is what i wanted to do..wht is the diff between . path/to/new/script and ./path/to/new/script ?

Comment: Just to make it doubly sure, there is a space between the first . and the rest of the path =>
. /path/to/your/script

Comment: Not semantically speaking...from execution perspective i asked

Comment: got it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017763/difference-between-and?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I assume (via the name) that this is a Weblogic environment setting script. It is usually called via the weblogic main script to set paths before starting/stopping the server - but you're trying to set paths within your own shell for whatever reason. I think your problem lays with the way you execute the script:

```
./setWLSEnv.sh # will execute the script and do nothing

. ./setWLSEnv.sh # (note starts with a "dot space")
```

The proposed second line should "source" the script within your environment and it will work

Check why this would work, by reading "man bash" and search inside for the definition of "source"

Answer (score 0):

In your file, replace `PATH=` with `PATH=$PATH:`. This takes the actual PATH variable and add all your new PATHs.

Add `export PATH` at the end of the file. This export the previous PATH with your changes.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/Users/cris/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/bin:/Users/cristianchiovari/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.ant_1.9.2/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Users/cristianchiovari/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/cristianchiovari/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/../oracle_common/modules/org.apache.maven_3.0.5/bin
export PATH
```

Comment: this behavior is only on MAC or on linux as well ? this script is provided by oracle weblogic and i doubt i have to modify it...

Comment: I added export path to the end but after script is done...the PATH content is gone as well :(

Comment: You can use in both MAC or linux.

Comment: Yes all this works for me as well if i run each command manually...my sh file pastebin.com/sSXRZd1s is coming from oracle weblogic used to set some variables before running some java stuff

Comment: So after running this ./setWLSEnv.sh the PATH variable is not modified like in the file even if i modify the file by adding at the end export PATH

Comment: You run this script manually? or is placed on `.bash_profile`?

Comment: i just go where it is and execute ./setWLSEnv.sh

Comment: To debug just do the following. Rerun `.bash_profile` by typing `. .bash_profile`. Then `echo $PATH` to check it. Then run this script with `bash -x ./setWLSEnv.sh`, this command let you see what the script do step by step. After that type again `echo $PATH`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18656/discussion-between-jherran-and-cris).